# I'm getting a 200 status response from API Server, but the account still exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Here's my current server stack:

-Server OS

- Ubuntu 16.04
  -Web Server
- NGINX
  -Server Application
- Loopback.js and PM2
  -Database
- MariaDB

I wrote a custom method in Loopback to delete an account by Id number.  When I use POSTMAN to test it, I get a 200 response however, when I manually check MariaDB(SELECT * from Account WHERE id=1111) it shows that the id/account still exists.

Here is the method I wrote for loopback:

```
   Account.deleteThisAccount = function (req, callback) {
    // check if req.accessToken exists
    if (!req.accessToken) throw new Error('Access token not provided');

    // check if req.accessToken has userId
    if (!req.accessToken.userId) {
        console.log('accessToken:', req.accessToken); // to see contents
        throw new Error('Access token does not contain userId');
    }
    Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
        .then((account) => {
            if (!account) {
                throw new Error('Cannot find user')
            }
            return Account.destroy({
                where: {
                    id: req.accessToken.userId
                }
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            callback(null);
        }).catch(error => {
            callback(error);
        })
}





 Account.remoteMethod(
        'deleteThisAccount', {
            http: {
                path: '/deleteThisAccount',
                verb: 'del'
            },
            accepts: [
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } }
            ],
            returns: 'hopefully this works'
        }
    )
```

Any ideas why I'm getting a 200 status response, but the account is NOT being deleted?

Here's a screen shot of when I attempt to run npm start on the remote server.
[image]

Comment: Since You already say to model `destroy by id` so why not just call it like this? `Account.destroyById(req.accessToken.userId)`

Comment: I did try that, but then I looked at the "accepts" in the custom method and it was expecting an object..so I gave it an object.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways:

1) call destroy on instance:

```
Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
    .then((account) => {
        if (!account) {
            throw new Error('Cannot find user')
        }
        return account.destroy();
    })
    ...
```

2) fix method call:

```
Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
    .then((account) => {
        if (!account) {
            throw new Error('Cannot find user')
        }
        return Account.destroy({where: {id: req.accessToken.userId}});
    })
    ...
```

If nothing helps make sure that You're getting proper `req.accessToken.userId`:

```
// check if req.accessToken exists
if (!req.accessToken) throw new Error('Access token not provided');

// check if req.accessToken has userId
if (!req.accessToken.userId) {
  console.log('accessToken:', req.accessToken); // to see contents
  throw new Error('Access token does not contain userId');
}

Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
    .then((account) => {
        if (!account) {
            throw new Error('Cannot find user')
        }
        return Account.destroy({where: {id: req.accessToken.userId}});
    })
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I've tried both ways that you've posted and the account still exists in the db.  Is there any additional info that I may have forgotten that would explain why destroy() doesn't work?

Comment: @VK1 can You do `console.log(req.accessTolen)` and put it's content to Your question? I suspect that  `req.accesssToken` does not contain `userId`

Comment: I've put in a console.log in the method so I can see the req.accessToken.  However, I'm not sure how /where I'm able to read the logs.  According to the loopback docs, I just need to start by type "node ." But as far as I know, it's already running on a remote server.  I'm quite lost right now.

Comment: I've tried starting the server in debug mode with: export DEBUG=*; npm start
 but that gives me the error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: @VK1 1. Kill that process using task manager or terminal. 2. Add `console.log(req.accessToken); process.exit(0);` above `Account.findById` and try again. No need for `DEBUG` simply run: `npm start`

Comment: @VK1 I've added example to my answer how to catch if access token not defined or does not contain `userId`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186516/discussion-between-vk1-and-num8er).